# Creating a chatbox and can't position chat messages on the right. Also, adding border creates unnecessary height.

Tags: html, css, chat

I'm trying to make a simple chatbox.
Until I add border It looks fine (width and height wise)

[image: Chat message example]

But when I add `border: solid 1px gray`, I get:

[image: Chat message example 2]

What causes this?

Also I'm trying to position messages sent by the user on the right with `float: right`:

[image: Full chat box screenshot]

However, as you can see, the next message sent ends up on the same line.

Thanks in advance!

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mendymsuoi/crc4q6gj/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated HTML and CSS ... See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crc4q6gj/2/)

```
<div>
  <div class="message">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="message me">
      <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="message">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Extra CSS

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.message p {
   margin: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much! I will accept in 7 mins.